# Why NodeJS execSync() is too slow when executing custom scripts

Tags: node.js, exec, child-process

I'm working on a server to server communication that must be **synchronous** on the client. I ended up using child_process.execSync()

The problem now is that execSync() is too slow executing node.js custom script file, for example:

```
// main.js
var res = execSync('node --version');
// TIME: 8 ms
```

Although, having a custom node script that only prints out the node version to the stdout, like:

```
// script.js:
process.stdout.write(process.version);
process.exit();
```

then:

```
// main.js
var res = execSync('node script.js');
// TIME: 135 ms !!!
```

this is almost 16x.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your numbers on my system. This is running on my Macbook Pro, home computer. Calling your first main.js for main1.js and second for main2.js and just adding `var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;` on the top of main1 and main2.

```
$ time node main1.js
v5.3.0


real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.075s
sys 0m0.022s

$ time node script.js
v5.3.0
real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.058s
sys 0m0.015s

$ time node main2.js
v5.3.0

real    0m0.166s
user    0m0.131s
sys 0m0.031s
```

Those numbers looks good to me.